# Bootstrap select multiple full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey i made a form with boostrap and now i have an issue.

I used

```
<select multible class="formt-control">
```

The Issue i want to see all 65 elements on the site. I tried to change the height and somehting other stuff but it does not work. Does anonye has an idea how to fix my issues?

The width is working because i used the container but the hight is my problem.

Here the complete project: http://jsfiddle.net/nA9vP/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property for height.

```
select.form-control{
    height:1000px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple class="form-control" size="100">
```